# Form that PUT and POST and DELETE together

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, forms, xmlhttprequest

I have a form with input fields filled with data from backend, a header section (always one header), and a rows section (can be more than one row). It looks like this:

```
<form>
<header id="header">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"value="jhon">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="smith">
    </div>
</header>
<details id="row" >
    <article id="article-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="article-name">Article Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article-name" value="article 1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="article-price">Article Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article-price" value="100">
        </div>
        <button id="delete-article-1">-</button>
    </article>
    <article id="article-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="article-name">Article Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article-name" value="article 2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="article-price">Article Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article-price" value="200">
        </div>
        <button id="delete-article-2">-</button>
    </article>
</details>
<footer>
    <button id="add-article-row">+</button>
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</footer>
</form>
```

on submit button click I want to perform a PUT request for the header section (or no request if there's not changes) and different action based on rows:

**CASE 1**: the rows ids are the same of the initial rows ids

- no request if there's no change to the initial values

  **OR**
- a PUT request if the values changes (update based on article id)

**CASE 2**: new rows added

- no request for the rows that has no changes to the initial values **AND** a POST request for the new rows (add an article)

  **OR**
- a PUT request if the values changes (update based on article id) **AND** a POST request for the new rows (add an article)

**CASE 3**: one or more rows is deleted

- no request for the rows that has no changes to the initial values **AND** a DELETE request for the deleted rows (based on article id)

  **OR**
- a PUT request if the values changes (update based on article id) **AND** a DELETE request for the deleted rows (based on article id)

**CASE 4**: new rows added **AND** one or more rows deleted

- no request for the rows that has no changes to the initial values **AND** a DELETE request for the deleted rows (based on article id) **AND** a POST request for the new rows (add an article)

  **OR**
- a PUT request if the values changes (update based on article id) **AND** a DELETE request for the deleted rows (based on article id) **AND** a POST request for the new rows (add an article)

The question is: How can I build a Form that can handle all of these actions together? Based on row-id I can loop every time the button is clicked and check the changed values, the new ones and the deleted ones, then send requests based on the correct use case, but I don't know if this is the correct way to setup this kind of form

PS: I'm using Laravel from backend and jQuery for AJAX requests

Thank you for the help

**EDIT:**

I create a sample jQuery file to simulate the form, getting the old data and the sending the new ones, here a JSFiddle: https://codepen.io/ufollettu/pen/LaLKpe?editors=1111

Is better to send a unique POST request to my BE controller, then manage the PUT/POST/DELETE logic in Laravel, or send multiple AJAX requests (one for header and one for each rows)?

NB: I need to rollback the data to the old one if a single request fail too

Comment: As far as possible you should accept `POST` for all actions since HTML only does define the `GET` and `POST` form method. You can submit other requests by JavaScript as long as enabled on client side, however, a fallback is recommendable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with a single request because PUT, POST, and DELETE are all different *types* of request.  If you're using AJAX, then you can define three methods to perform a form submission; one per type of request.

So for example, based off a single `onClick` event, you could pivot in your JavaScript layer based on which inputs had values, or pivot on some other aspect of your application state, in order to choose which method to use, and hence which request type to make.

You can also perform multiple requests based on a single click, by calling all three methods in succession.

In any case, it would seem like a better solution would be to apply the above methodology on a per-row basis, rather than on the entire form.  That would probably allow you to generalize your solution to a row, and allow you to add as many rows as you want.